# Can we make the rank of twist of a given elliptic curve over number field $0$ by infinitely many ways?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$.

Does there exists an infinitely many $D\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that rank of $E_D/K$ is $0$ ?

Maybe this is an open problem, so
weak problem can be :In the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{l_1},\sqrt{l_2},・・・,\sqrt{l_n})(l_i\in \Bbb{Q})$, can we say more about the above problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general number field, this is not always true: see [1], which (among studying the phenomenon in general), gives the example of $E:y^2 = x^3+\frac54 x^2 -2x-7$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{-11})$ as an example of a curve for which $E_D$ has negative root number for *every* D. Assuming BSD, this would mean that the rank of $E_D$ is *never* 0.

The more general question of the distribution of ranks of quadratic twists over arbitrary number fields has been studied by Klagsbrun–Mazur–Rubin [2]: see, for example, Conj. 7.12, which gives a precise conjecture for the average rank of $E_D$ (as $D$ varies over $K^\times/K^{\times 2}$), generalising Goldfeld's conjecture. I'm not sure if examples such as the one above exist when $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{l_1}, \ldots,\sqrt{l_n})$, but this paper would be a good place to start.

On the other hand, a positive answer to your question is well-known when $K=\mathbb Q$: the existence of a single $D$ was first proven in [3] on the analytic side (see [4] for a proof for infinitely many $D$), and the algebraic side follows from Wiles' modularity theorem + Gross–Zagier's proof of rank 0 BSD. More recently, the work of Alex Smith has proven Goldfeld's conjecture almost unconditionally.

For general number fields, if you insist on only considering $E_D$ where $D$ is an integer, than I'm not really sure what the answer should be: the set of $E_D$ is an extremely sparse subset of the set of quadratic twists, where $D$ should vary over $K^\times/K^{\times 2}$.

On the other hand, if you're happy to vary $D$ over $K^\times/K^{\times 2}$, then Smith's methods almost certainly extend to general number fields as well, at least to some extent. So I'd imagine that, in cases where your statement is true, a proof is probably within reach.

[1] T. Dokchitser, V. Dokchitser, Elliptic curves with all quadratic twists of positive rank. Acta
Arith. 137 (2009)

[2] Klagsbrun, Zev, Barry Mazur, and Karl Rubin. "Disparity in Selmer ranks of quadratic twists of elliptic curves." Annals of Mathematics (2013): 287-320.

[3] Bump, Daniel, Solomon Friedberg, and Jeffrey Hoffstein. "Nonvanishing theorems for L-functions of modular." Invent. math 102 (1990): 543-618.

[4] K. Ono and C. Skinner, ‘Non-vanishing of quadratic twists of modular -functions’, Invent. Math. 134(3) (1998),
651–660.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and sophisticated answer. In fact,I was just about to study [3].　Over $\Bbb{Q}$, does there exist a twist by $D$ such that $D$ has arbitrary many distinct prime factors? More precisely, is it true that for all $r$ and for all elliptic curves $E/\Bbb{Q}$, there exists a quadratic field extension $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ such that $\omega(D) \ge r$ and the rank of $E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is $0$, where $\omega(D)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $D$?

Comment: So I realise that I made a mistake and that [3] should maybe be replaced by https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050275: [3] just shows the existence of a single twist. I'm not knowledgeable enough to say whether or not what you want already follows from [4], but it should definitely follow from Smith's work, since the density of squarefree integers with $\omega(D)<r$ is $0$.

Comment: 1. Does there a generalization for cubic twist or other degree (except for quadratic) extensions ? I mean,does there known elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$, whose rank does not gain under

Comment: For cubic twists, there is very recent work of [Alpoge-Bhargava-Shnidman](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.10730.pdf). You can also look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12864) and the cited references. This is a highly active research topic in general.