# Does there exist infinitely many quadratic field such that rank of elliptic curves gains at most 2?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic extension of number field.
Most elliptic curves $E/K$ will have the property that $rank(E/K) \le rank(E/L) +2$.

Is it known for an arbitrary $E/K$, does there exists infinitely many $L/K$: quadratic such that $rank(E/L) \le rank(E/K) +2$?

Comment: I don't know if this is known when $K$ is an arbitrary number field, although it is expected that the stronger inequality $\mathrm{rk}(E/L) - \mathrm{rk}(E/K)\le 1$ should hold for $100\%$ of $L=K(\sqrt{D})/K$. But it is known when $K=\mathbb Q$ - see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795709/can-we-make-the-rank-of-twist-of-a-given-elliptic-curve-over-number-field-0-by/4796003#4796003): note that if $L = K(\sqrt{D})$, then $\mathrm{rk}(E/L) - \mathrm{rk}(E/K) = \mathrm{rk}(E_D/K)$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 What is the definition of 100% here ?

Comment: For $\mathbb Q$, you can define $\Sigma_X= \{d \text{ squarefree } : |d|\le X \}$. $100\%$ means that the limit as $X\to\infty $ of $\frac{\#\{\text{ good } d\in \Sigma_X\}}{\#\Sigma_X}$ is $1$. For general number fields, there is a similar, slightly more complicated definition of $\Sigma_X$.